# Can I change the interval of a previously created matplotlib FuncAnimation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to figure out if is there any way for me to change the interval of an existing matplotlib FuncAnimation. I want to be able to adjust the speed of the animation according to the user input.

I found a similar question [How do I change the interval between frames (python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25829345/how-do-i-change-the-interval-between-frames-python), but since it got no answer I thought I would ask it anyway.

A minimal example of what I need and have is:

```
"""
Based on Matplotlib Animation Example

author: Jake Vanderplas
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658472/animating-a-moving-dot
"""
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import Tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg


class AnimationWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.fig = plt.figure(0, figsize=(10, 10))

        self.anim = None

        self.speed = 2

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('resize_event', self.on_resize)

        self.bar = tk.Scale(self, from_=0.25, to=10, resolution=0.25, command=self.change_play_speed, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.bar.pack(fill=tk.X)

    def start_animation(self):
        ax = plt.axes()

        self.x = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, 0.01)
        self.line, = ax.plot(self.x, np.sin(self.x))

        # The return needs to be assigned to a variable in order to prevent the cleaning by the GC
        self.anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animation_update, frames=100,
                                            interval=100/self.speed, blit=True, repeat=False)

    def animation_update(self, i):
        self.line.set_ydata(np.sin(self.x + i / 10.0))  # update the data
        return self.line,

        return tuple(self.annotation)

    def change_play_speed(self, speed):
        self.speed = float(speed)

        # This works but I think somehow the previous animation remains
        #self.anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animation_update, frames=100, interval=100/self.speed, blit=True, repeat=False)

    def on_resize(self, event):
        """This function runs when the window is resized.
         It's used to clear the previous points from the animation which remain after resizing the windows."""

        plt.cla()


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()

    rw = AnimationWindow(root)
    rw.pack()

    rw.start_animation()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the change speed function I have a commented solution to this problem. This solution presents two main problems: it is most likely very inefficient (I think); and I haven't figured out a way for me to delete the previous animation which results in flickering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recomment to delete the animation. One option for more complex animations is of course to program them manually. Using a timer which repeatedly calls the update function is actually not much more code than creating the `FuncAnimation`.

However in this case the solution is very simple. Just change the interval of the underlying `event_source`:

```
def change_play_speed(self, speed):
    self.speed = float(speed)
    self.anim.event_source.interval = 100./self.speed
```