# Is there any way to set variable interval for matplotlib in Tkinter (python)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to graph readings received from a weight scale connected to Arduino. The Arduino using bluetooth sends data to RPi and I successfully made a live GUI. The issue is, I am trying to have a SpinBox or some sort of counter that can adjust the interval of at which the graph updates. I have tried using the variables for the interval in the FuncAnimation but it does not seem to work. 
I have brute forced and noticed that once the code is executed, the interval is set to the initial value it receives and sticks to it. While loop does not work well with the objective I have to achieve. I have attached the code below too. Please note I am a beginner in Python.

```
import serial
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import time
import read_arduino

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/rfcomm0', 115200)
ser.flushInput()

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x400+200+100')
root.title('This is my root window')
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(root)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)

tab_control.add(tab1, text='First')
tab_control.add(tab2, text='Second')

# var =IntVar()
# var.set(300)
# incr=1000
# spin = Spinbox(tab1, from_=200, to=1000, width=5, textvariable=var)

xar = [0]
yar = [0]

style.use('ggplot')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 2.5))
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Weight")
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.set_aspect("auto")
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)

ax1.set_ylim(0, 100)
line, = ax1.plot(xar, yar, 'blue',marker='x')
plt.tight_layout()
dum= StringVar()
lbl = Label(tab1, textvariable=dum).grid(row=2,column=2)


def animate(i):


    x=get_avg()
    yar.append(x)
    xar.append(i)
    line.set_data(xar, yar)
    ax1.set_xlim(0, i+1)
    dum.set(x)


def get_avg():
    n = 60
    val=str(0.0)
    for n in range(1,60):
        val=str(ser.readline(),"utf-8").strip("\n")

    return val

plotcanvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, tab1)
plotcanvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=5,column=0)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000, blit=False)
tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you looked into the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41882736/can-i-change-the-interval-of-a-previously-created-matplotlib-funcanimation)?

Comment: I did look at it but I cannot seem to incorporate it into my code. The thing is, the ani statement only runs once for me and never again. Trying to make it run again using a while loop only makes things worse. Any help relatively would be appreciated.